# Oracle Protocol Violation following OutOfMemory

Tags: jvm, out-of-memory, ojdbc

one of my batch job (it is really heavy to handle) throws below exception and logs.

to be honest I am lost at some point if the Protocol Violation caused by memory issue vice versa.

```
2021-05-08 13:55:52,190 ERROR TransactionAspectSupport - Application exception overridden by rollback exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CBlobAccessor.checkAndAllocateLobPrefetchMemory(T4CBlobAccessor.java:319)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CBlobAccessor.handlePrefetch(T4CBlobAccessor.java:504)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CBlobAccessor.unmarshalOneRow(T4CBlobAccessor.java:191)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIrxd.unmarshal(T4CTTIrxd.java:934)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIrxd.unmarshal(T4CTTIrxd.java:853)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.readRXD(T4C8Oall.java:699)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:337)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1010)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1185)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1275)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3576)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3620)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2542)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:119)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1716)
        at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
        at com.***.property.dao.hibernate.CompanySystemPropertyHibernateDao.retrieveCompanySystemProperty(CompanySystemPropertyHibernateDao.java:107)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor574.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
2021-05-08 14:05:46,590 ERROR TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC rollback failed
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doRollback(HibernateTransactionManager.java:680)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:846)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:823)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:493)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:264)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68.refresh(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor571.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:64)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC rollback failed
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:200)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doRollback(HibernateTransactionManager.java:677)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:459)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.doOROLLBACK(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:68)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.doRollback(T4CConnection.java:649)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.rollback(PhysicalConnection.java:3893)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.rollback(NewProxyConnection.java:855)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollbackAndResetAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:213)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:192)
        ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 1):

This can happen during LOB prefetch if there are multiple LOB columns and a large fetch size.

With LOB prefetch, the server sends data along with the LOB locator for performance reasons. By default, it sends the first 4k bytes of data of very LOB. The driver also prefetches rows 10 by 10 by default. So if you have 10 LOBs per row every "row fetch" roundtrip will consume 10*10*4k, so 400k bytes. Of course this assumes that every LOB has more than 4k bytes worth of data.

To tune the driver and avoid this error, you can either reduce the default fetch size or reduce the LOB prefetch size.

There is a JDBC property [CONNECTION_PROPERTY_DEFAULT_LOB_PREFETCH_SIZE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#CONNECTION_PROPERTY_DEFAULT_LOB_PREFETCH_SIZE) to configure a different LOB prefetch size. You can set it to "1000" (1k bytes) to reduce how much memory will be consumed on the driver by LOBs.

Comment: Well, thanks for the light. The table I am fetching is not a big one. I am assuming other jobs in my app also consumes too much so that this query failed. It could've been any one of the queries in my app.

Comment: Yes this parameter applies to all queries. There is also an option to fine-tune the lob prefetch size on a per statement basis (see OracleStatement->setLobPrefetchSize​(int value))